# How to use SSIS Merge Join - not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to reproduce in SSIS a simple inner join:

```
select *
from journee jou
inner join journee_elp jep on jep.journee_fk = jou.id
```

So I did in SSIS:

[image]

[image]

Both source have IsSorted set to True, and the joined columns have SortKeyPosition = 1

For the 1st test, I add the where on both of the source to restrict the perimeter
(the SQL statement returns 19 lines for this test) :

[image]

This is the behaviour I was expecting, glad of this success, I decided to remove the WHERE from the left source...

But no more matching...

[image]

Did I missed something?
I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: Please be so kind and provide consumable sample data (no screenshots) and explain which would be the output you would have expected basing on these samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add an order by on the key in addition to the SortKeyPosition = 1 and it worked